# on select autocomplete field fetch the record from database in handsontable

Tags: javascript, php, handsontable

I want to auto fetch name and qty once code is selected.

Following is the code I tried.

```
        var $container = $("#data");
        var items = "";
        $container.handsontable({
          startRows: 8,
          startCols: 3,
          rowHeaders: true,
          colHeaders: true,
          minSpareRows: 1,
          contextMenu: true,
          colHeaders: ['CODE','NAME','QTY'],
          afterChange : function(arr, op) {
              alert('test');     //DOES NOT WORK...
        },
          columns: [
            {
              data:'code',
              type: 'autocomplete',
              source: function (query, process) {
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'codes.php',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: {
                    query: query
                  },
                  success: function (response) {

                      process(response);

                  }
                });
              },
            },
            {
                    data: "name"
            }, 
            {} 
          ]



        });
```

The afterChange event does not work. I am following this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wvXvJ/15/.. It is working in there I have no idea what is wrong in the above code
Please help

Comment: look at F12 of youre browser before runnign code and check for warning or error in the console

Comment: Not getting any error...

Comment: paste youre code here and does seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/wvXvJ/54/

Comment: Is the jquery.handsontable.full.js and jquery.handsontable.full.css paid libraries and are not available/ disabled for live servers ?  anything like that..

Comment: look here https://handsontable.com/ it used to be a free library. now it is a paid version

Comment: student can apply for a free version https://handsontable.com/pricing.html